# does mysql undo changes if you kill thread?

Tags: sql, mysql

i ran a delete rows query. it was taking too long so i killed the thread from administration. did it undo the changes to the table/?

Comment: What table storage engine type are you using (MyISAM, InnoDB, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnoDB` will rollback the transaction.

`MyISAM` will leave the changes and possible even the table in corrupt state.